# How to parent texture on background in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can I put texture on my background image? In my top down game I have scrolling background image and an obstacles (ball,shoes,etc..). My problem is how can I attached those texture on my background image that scrolling down and those texture will follow the background.

Here is the screenshot of my game  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl03R.png

Codes

```
 // Load the sprite sheet as a texture
    cat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat.png"));
    catsprite = new Sprite(cat);
    player = new Rectangle();
    player.width = 20;
    player.height = 80;
    player.x = 300;
    player.y = 0;

    basketball = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("equip/Basketball.png"));
    ball = new Circle();
    ball.x = 150;
    ball.y = 150;
    ball.radius = basketball.getWidth() / 4;
    ball.setPosition(350,500);

    shoes= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("equip/Shoes.png"));
    sprite_shoes = new Sprite(shoes);
    rectShoes =  new Rectangle();
    rectShoes.setPosition(100,300);

      //background
    Background1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("floor.png"));
    Background2 = Background1;
    yMax = -1270;
    yCoordBg1 = yMax*(-1);
    yCoordBg2 = 0;
```

Render

```
    camera.update();
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
    yCoordBg1+= BACKGROUND_MOVE_SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    yCoordBg2 = yCoordBg1 + yMax;  // We move the background, not the camera
    if (yCoordBg1 <= 0) {
        yCoordBg1 = yMax*(-1);
        yCoordBg2 = 0;
    }

    spriteBatch.draw(Background1, 0,yCoordBg1);
    spriteBatch.draw(Background2, 0,yCoordBg2);
    spriteBatch.draw(shoes,rectShoes.x,rectShoes.y);
    spriteBatch.draw(basketball, ball.x-ball.radius, ball.y-ball.radius);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame,player.x, player.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to move the player and the camera in stead of the background and all objects that should be tied to it. It makes it easier to understand and work with.

Comment: Thank you @p.streef. How can I tied those objects and use the camera that follow my player? my background image is png format 720x1280.

Comment: Think of your background as the world and make it repeat. then when you move the player, you also move the camera.

Comment: Okay sir Got it :)

Comment: Maybe it does not, but sometimes it is better to supply people with an answer to an unasked question that with an answer to a question they think will help them.